# xfce4-session-manager - does not turn off your computer

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, logout, session-manager

I use ArchLinux and Xfce 4.8

when in xfce4-session-manager I select Reboot or ShutDown
my computer just logout.

To turn it off i have to use e.g. 'halt' in terminal.

It began a few days ego.
Someone can help me ?

Comment: This happened to me a couple days ago since doing a full system upgrade, did you find anything out?

Answer (score 0):

I had once a similar problem with a fresh installation. There was something missing re PolicyKit/ConsoleKit (can't remember the details, sorry, but it should be fairly easy to check you have all the packages you need).
Also I had to modify **~/.xinitrc** to launch XFCE with this command:

```
exec ck-launch-session startxfce4
```

I hope this helps.